# Azure - Disconnect Virtual Network Gateway

Tags: azure

We just deployed ADFS with a couple of domain controllers to Azure. We're in hurricane country, and we'd like our cloud hosted services to continue to function in case our data center gets blown away in the next big one. So now that we're deployed, I need to test and validate by disconnecting Azure from our data center and validate that everything still works. There doesn't seem to be a way to shutdown or disconnect the virtual network gateway. Any ideas here? TIA ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ASM Mode (Classic)**:

In classic mode all you have to do is disconnect with the cmdlet below. To reconnect just change the last parameter to -Connect.

```
Set-AzureVNetGateway -VNetName "<VNetName>" -LocalNetworkSiteName "<LocalSiteName>" -Disconnect
```

**ARM Mode**:

In ARM, you have to remove the Connection resource and recreate it as soon as you are ready to reconnect.

```
Remove-AzureRmVirtualNetworkGatewayConnection -Name "<ConnectionName>" -ResourceGroupName "<RgName>"
```

Comment: Thanks. I created everything in ARM mode. Can I use ASM mode commands on my resources and still be fine?

Comment: ASM commands will not work on ARM resources. They will simply not find the resource you are trying to manage.

Comment: Great. If you think my answer resolved the problem for you, plz accept it as an answer.

Comment: I'll try it out, then come back and set as answered.

Comment: OK I was able to work out commands to delete the connection and recreate it. The -Whatif switch tells me that the commands will run successfully. I'll wait until I can schedule a maintenance window to do the testing. Thanks again for the help.